# Admob banner with tabbar and navbar isn't working

Tags: ios, admob, xcode7

I'm trying to add my admob banner right above the navbar (or anywhere !) it just doesn't show any ads, neither any errors, but when I remove the Viewcontroller from the tabbar and make it the initial viewcontroller (just wanted to test) it works just fine.

(I have tried a lot of solutions like changing the banner to the top or change its Y position but it didn't work out)

what is the problem ?

Comment: Add some relevant code to your question.

Comment: @DanielStorm I don't think it's about the code, because the same viewcontroller with the same code works fine when I move it out of the tabBar, so I think to rephrase my question : does admob banners work with both tabbar and navbar (both in the same viewcontroller) or should I use native ads ?